# AWS EBS volume not showing up windows disk management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, block-storage

I created an EC2 Windows instance with gp2 EBS volume.

But on logging into the windows system and checking on Disk Management, I don't find the added volume space under both un-allocated or primary partition.

I created the instance using an *AWS launch template* and the Device name of EBS was given as *xvda*.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of EBS from *xvda* to *xvdd* in ec2 launch template and creating a new instance solved the issue.

Seems like any *EBS Device name* above C alphabetically is not shown in Disk Management, which is weird.

For those who cannot create a new instance, create a new volume from EBS volume and attach it to instance manually and restart the windows machine. Then it would come up in the Disk management.

AWS now note that:

> Recommended device names for Windows: /dev/sda1 for root volume.
> xvd[f-p] for data volumes.

i.e. for **windows EC2 EBS (non root) volumes** choose from the list of "Device Name"s a name that

- starts with xvd
- ends with a letter from f to p

Comment: This solved my issue, I had to detach, delete the volume that would not show up, then create a new one.